# Need assistance getting a Spring form to work

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, dojo

I'm in the middle of writing a Spring webapp and things were going well. I'm trying to write a form that allows an admin to change some basic user details. However, on submission of the form I keep getting an HTTP 400 error saying the request sent by the client was "Syntactically Incorrect". It doesn't offer any actual useful info though and I've really looked over everything and have no idea what I could be doing wrong. Here is the JSP:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<div align="center">
<s:url value="/admin/access" var="access_url" />
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" dojoType="dijit.form.Form">
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onSubmit">
    if (!this.validate()) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Username: </td>
    <td>
        <sf:input path="username" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" trim="true" required="true"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Password: </td>
    <td>
        <sf:input path="password" type="password" dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" required="true"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Enabled: </td>
    <td>
        Yes<sf:radiobutton path="enabled" value="true" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton"/> 
        No<sf:radiobutton path="enabled" value="false" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Admin: </td>
    <td>
        Yes<sf:radiobutton path="isAdmin" value="true" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton"/> 
        No<sf:radiobutton path="isAdmin" value="false" dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton"/>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right" colspan="2">
        <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</sf:form>
</div>
```

Here is the method that will end up being called in the Controller, though it's not getting that far:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/editUser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitEditUser(@RequestParam("user") NFIUser nfiUser) {
```

And here is the GET mapping from the same controller, though the form displays perfectly with all values being mapped properly into the form so I don't know that there is any issue here:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/admin/editUser", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void showEditUser(Model model, @RequestParam("username") String username) {
    ....
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
}
```

Anyway, if anyone has any thoughts please let me know. I've been successfully solving errors all I'm encountering all day but I can't seem to see any issue with this one. Thanks.

Comment: Your sf:form tag doesn't have an action.  I think you need to drop your "admin/editUser" in the action attribute of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was a combination of what everyone left here. Normally for Spring you don't need an action method on a form but in this case it turned out, due to how I was loading the form one ended up being needed in the end to overwrite the action that was being loaded by Spring.

Also removing the @RequestParam("user") bit solved the problem of the 400 error. Because I was using spring form tags this time so that everything was bound nicely I guess I didn't need the RequestParam bit. Clearly I don't yet have the best understanding of when those are and aren't needed.

Anyway, I marked up people's answers, but technically none of them was the full solution so I posted this. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove the @reqiestParam fotm the submitEditUser method.